# Seeing different values between modern and classic list views

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-rest-api, list-view

I have a SPO site with a modern experience list of about 4,000 items. I used "Edit in grid view" from the modern experience to make a lot (almost all the items) changes to values in one of my columns. It all seemed to work...

I'm then using REST calls to retrieve the items. I tried filtering on the new values in the columns, but it wasn't working. At first I thought I have my REST call wrong or the $filter, but when I checked I saw the old values for the column and also that the modified date hadn't been updated either.

I went back to my list and confirmed (in the modern interface) that the values had indeed been updated. I saw the new value, but the modified date was not today.

Then for kicks and giggles I clicked the "return to classic SharePoint" link to see if there was anything in the old views that could help me figure out what was going on. In classic view I didn't see the updated values -- just the old ones.

Anybody know what is going on?

An additional clue (maybe) is at the top of the modern experience list there is a "sync" icon. Other lists say something like "This list is in sync. Last sync: 2 minutes ago." But on this list is says "syncing changes" and has said that for the last hour or so. Not sure if it is related, but I suspect it might be.

Comment: What type of columns are affected?

Comment: I didn't test all of them but modified, number, date, single line of text, person.

Comment: I think changes you made in modern experience grid views are not added/synced to list properly.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the bulk editor by "Edit Grid View" is not 100% reliable; BUT, you have another alternative to do your bulk edit using PnP PowerShell. I recently had a similar request where the requirement needed to do a bulk edit on items over 2000 and by "Edit grid view" I had several issues and with two different tenants I had the same issue. Anyway, I believe that PnP PowerShell is the best alternative for bulk update items.